Probability when does order matter?
I was solving a probability question where I have 52 cards in a deck which contains 4 aces and I have to randomly draw five different cards. What is the probability that among the five cards you selected:
(a) There are no aces at all?
(b) There are exactly two aces?
I am not sure if I should consider that order matters  and there is are also 4 identical  cards , I assumed that order matters
so I have  $52 \cdot 51 \cdot 50 \cdot 49 \cdot 48$  as total combinations yet I have 4 identical cards so I believe I should divide by $4!$ since they are getting repeated
so when I approached section (a) I started with the opposite case   where I have all $4$ chosen beings aces  and the last can be any of the$ 48$ remaining cards so I  have $ 48$  yet when swapping locations I get a different set as long as I am not swapping identical cards  so I divided by 4! and multiplied by $5!$
so I considered a) to be
$$ \frac{48\cdot 5}{ \Big(\frac{52\cdot51\cdot50\cdot49\cdot48}{4!}\Big)}$$
or is this the type of question where we can't decide and should basically solve for each case ?"this got clarified "
so I am asking about the specific case of dealing with (a) and (b) when the aces are considered identical and the order matters so 48 different cards 4 identical cards

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

thank you i will read and apply

Are you asking how to deal with question such as (a) and (b), or are you asking about the probability of four aces?

As a general rule, if you have a probability question dealing with cards, dice, balls in an urn, etc., and you can solve it correctly while considering some objects identical and/or ignoring order, you should get the exact same answer if you consider the objects distinct and also consider order. Cards do not jump back in the deck just because we look at them more closely.

Four aces is "opposite" no aces in a sense, but not in any sense that helps you compute the probabilities. The cases are not equivalent to each other and they do not cover all probabilities, so you can't assume their probabilities are equal or that they add up to $1$.

@DavidK to deal with them not the second option

Order matters when the order in which items appear matter.
If it is a counting problem, the question will specify whether order matters or not. But if it is a probability problem, nothing may be specified, and you can choose to treat it in either way, but you have to take care to maintain consistency in treating the numerator and denominator.
Since nothing has been specified for this question, it is easier to take that order doesn't matter, so for no aces.
$$\;\;(a) Pr = \frac{\binom{48}5}{\binom{52}5}$$
and for two aces
$$\;\;{b) Pr = \frac{\binom42\binom{48}3}{\binom{52}5}}$$
If you want to treat it as if order matters,  the computation  will become more complicated, viz
$$ (b) \;\;\frac{4\cdot3\cdot{48}\cdot{47}\cdot{46}\times\frac{5!}{2!3!}}{52\cdot51\cdot50\cdot49\cdot48} $$
to maintain comsistency between favorable events and total events
In brief, for this problem, either use combinations or permutations for both numerator and denominator to correctly compute probability

I understand the answers you got for a and b  when order does not matter in the first we choose 5 out of the 48 where we removed the 4 aces  , how are you approaching b when order matters if I may ask

I would rather  phrase your question whether a particular order has been specified, or whether all possible orders need to be taken into account. Since no particular order has been specified, while using the multiplicative way, we have multiplied by $\frac{5!}{3!2!}$ to convert the particular order of the numerator (ace-ace-others-others=others) into all possible orders.

and may be a stupid question yet I think I don't fully understand how to reach such ratio if you have some time I would value more details on how to reach it thanks

The denominator in the multiplicative method is cleary a permutation, whereas the numerator is for the particular order AAXXX (where X is for non-aces). You should be able to see that we need to multiply by $\frac{5!}{2!3!}$ to make the denominator also a permutation .

@dareen When you were computing four aces you multiplied by $5$ to account for the fact that the non-ace could occur in any of the five places in the five cards. For two aces there are $\binom53$ different sets of places the non-aces could occur. That's the factor $5!/(3!2!)$.

@DavidK thanks I did not connect it in this way

Whether or not the order matters should be in the description of the event.  It might more a question of the English (or whatever) language.

What is the probability than I get no aces when dealt 5 cards

This is fairly unambiguous, considering the order will not matter.

What is the probability that I get exactly two aces

Almost certainly the intention is that not just Ace, Ace, Other, Other, Other but also Other, Ace, Other, Ace, Other, etc will be included.
In some cases, it is less clear when the intention is but the problem is usually in the interpretation of the description and not the mathematics.

I see so it is not like there is a standard interpretation for this type of question , it is more related to what the author intends and how well he makes that intention clear

I think I might then update the question to be more focused on the mathematics since I am also interested on how the calculation will be made when there is repetitions and impotence for order but this certainly gave me some clearlification
